# How to add my customized class to sklearn pipeline properly?

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm having trouble trying to include my own class in the sklearn pipeline. I am sharing my try on the very basic titanic dataset below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, chi2, VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

X, y = fetch_openml("titanic", version=1, as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)
X.drop(["cabin","boat","body","home.dest"],axis=1,inplace=True)

drop_index = X.isna().any(axis=1)[X.isna().any(axis=1)].index
X = X.drop(index=drop_index)
y = y.drop(index=drop_index)

class category_encoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, encoder):
        self.encoder_name = encoder
        self.encoder = None
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if self.encoder_name == "ordinalencoder":
            self.encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
            self.encoder.fit(X)
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(X), columns=X.columns)
    
numeric_features = ["age", "fare"]
ohe_features = ["sex"]
oe_features = ["embarked", "pclass"]

numeric = Pipeline(steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer()), 
                          ("scaler", StandardScaler()), 
                          ("transformer", MinMaxScaler())])

categoric_ohe = Pipeline(steps=[("encoder_ohe", category_encoder(encoder="ordinalencoder"))])


preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("num", numeric, numeric_features), 
                                               ("cat", categoric_ohe, ohe_features)])

param_grid = [{"classifier": [LogisticRegression()], 
               "classifier__penalty": ["l2"], 
               "classifier__C": np.logspace(0, 4, 10)}, 
              {"classifier": [RandomForestClassifier()],
               "classifier__n_estimators": [10, 100, 1000], 
               "classifier__max_features": [1, 2, 3]}]

full_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), 
                            ("feature_eliminator", VarianceThreshold()), 
                            ("classifier", LogisticRegression())])

model = GridSearchCV(full_pipe, 
                     param_grid, 
                     cv=5, verbose=0, 
                     n_jobs = -1, 
                     scoring="accuracy")

model.fit(X,y)
```

When I run this code sequentially, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(X,y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:926, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    924 refit_start_time = time.time()
    925 if y is not None:
--> 926     self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    927 else:
    928     self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:390, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    364 """Fit the model.
    365 
    366 Fit all the transformers one after the other and transform the
   (...)
    387     Pipeline with fitted steps.
    388 """
    389 fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 390 Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    391 with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    392     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:348, in Pipeline._fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    346     cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    347 # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 348 X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    349     cloned_transformer,
    350     X,
    351     y,
    352     None,
    353     message_clsname="Pipeline",
    354     message=self._log_message(step_idx),
    355     **fit_params_steps[name],
    356 )
    357 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    358 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
    359 # from the cache.
    360 self.steps[step_idx] = (name, fitted_transformer)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py:349, in NotMemorizedFunc.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    348 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349     return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:893, in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891 with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892     if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894     else:
    895         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py:675, in ColumnTransformer.fit_transform(self, X, y)
    672 self._validate_column_callables(X)
    673 self._validate_remainder(X)
--> 675 result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    677 if not result:
    678     self._update_fitted_transformers([])

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py:606, in ColumnTransformer._fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted, column_as_strings)
    600 transformers = list(
    601     self._iter(
    602         fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True, column_as_strings=column_as_strings
    603     )
    604 )
    605 try:
--> 606     return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    607         delayed(func)(
    608             transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,
    609             X=_safe_indexing(X, column, axis=1),
    610             y=y,
    611             weight=weight,
    612             message_clsname="ColumnTransformer",
    613             message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)),
    614         )
    615         for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(transformers, 1)
    616     )
    617 except ValueError as e:
    618     if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1046, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1043 if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1044     self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
-> 1046 while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1047     pass
   1049 if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:
   1050     # The iterable was consumed all at once by the above for loop.
   1051     # No need to wait for async callbacks to trigger to
   1052     # consumption.

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:861, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    859     return False
    860 else:
--> 861     self._dispatch(tasks)
    862     return True

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:779, in Parallel._dispatch(self, batch)
    777 with self._lock:
    778     job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 779     job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    780     # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    781     # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to
    782     # grow. To ensure correct results ordering, .insert is
    783     # used (rather than .append) in the following line
    784     self._jobs.insert(job_idx, job)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py:208, in SequentialBackend.apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206 def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207     """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208     result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209     if callback:
    210         callback(result)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py:572, in ImmediateResult.__init__(self, batch)
    569 def __init__(self, batch):
    570     # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571     # arguments in memory
--> 572     self.results = batch()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:262, in BatchedCalls.__call__(self)
    258 def __call__(self):
    259     # Set the default nested backend to self._backend but do not set the
    260     # change the default number of processes to -1
    261     with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262         return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:262, in <listcomp>(.0)
    258 def __call__(self):
    259     # Set the default nested backend to self._backend but do not set the
    260     # change the default number of processes to -1
    261     with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262         return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:216, in _FuncWrapper.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    214 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    215     with config_context(**self.config):
--> 216         return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:893, in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891 with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892     if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894     else:
    895         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:434, in Pipeline.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    432 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
    433 if hasattr(last_step, "fit_transform"):
--> 434     return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    435 else:
    436     return last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step).transform(Xt)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:855, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    852     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    853 else:
    854     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 855     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

Input In [20], in category_encoder.transform(self, X, y)
     12 def transform(self, X, y=None):
---> 13     return pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(X), columns=X.columns)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

What I want to create with class is that it takes the necessary information from the data according to the encoder used with the fit function and keeps it in its structure, and then encode it according to them while testing. The error I got seems to be that he can't see the information obtained with fit while transforming, so how do I avoid it?

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You're not abiding by the sklearn API in your `__init__` method.  It should be just

```py
    def __init__(self, encoder_name):
        self.encoder_name = encoder_name
```

(note that your calling of it will now need to use `encoder_name`, not `encoder`, as parameter).

The problem is the way sklearn clones estimators for use in grid search.  See the Developer's Guide, [Instantiation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#instantiation) and [get_params and set_params](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#get-params-and-set-params).

---

All that said, I don't understand the point of this custom estimator.  Note that you can swap out encoders in a pipeline as though they were hyperparameters (see [the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters)).